# Задача с использованием событий

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

У меня есть боковая меню с установленным стилем margin-left: -240px;.Как при клике сделать чтобы она выдвигалась и при втором клике задвигалась???

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <style>
.mainmenu{
  width: 250px;
  height: 638px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: -240px;
  transition-property: margin-left;
  transition-duration: 2s;

  </style>
</head>
<body class="chatbg">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="mainmenu" id="menu" onclick="scrolMenu()"></div>
<div class="chat"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function scrolMenu() {
var main = document.getElementById('menu');
main.style.marginLeft = "0px";
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Изучите `javascript`

Comment: Изучено. Но со временем немного забыто. Событие онклик я сдела но как ее вернуть в исходную позицию я не знаю

Comment: Хотябы дайте наводку

Comment: Для этого хотя бы дайте код ваш рабочий, или полу рабочий, вы вопрос изначально плохо сформулировали.

Comment: добавил, на ссылку в скрипте не обращайте внимания я просто уже не стал удалять итак все понятно здесь

Comment: Да и я поправил ваш вопрос, но только оно нечего не выводит на экран.

Comment: все стили задал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <style>
      .mainmenu {
      width: 250px;
      height: 638px;
      background-color: gray;
      margin-left: -240px;
      transition-property: margin-left;
      transition-duration: 2s;
  </style>
</head>

<body class="chatbg">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="mainmenu" id="menu" onclick="scrolMenu()"></div>
  <div class="chat"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var isClicked = false;

    function scrolMenu() {
    var main = document.getElementById('menu');
      if (!isClicked) {        
        main.style.marginLeft = "0px";
        isClicked = true;
      } else {
        main.style.marginLeft = "-240px";
        isClicked = false;
      }


    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручил)

Comment: @AlexMorgenshtern и сколько бесполезного `javascript` кода написал, вместо двух строк.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Chat</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="chatbg">
     <div class="header"></div>
     <div class="mainmenu" id="menu" onclick="scrolMenu()"></div>
     <div class="chat"></div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
          function scrolMenu() {
               $('#menu').toggleClass('active');
          };

     </script>
     <style>
     .mainmenu{
        width: 250px;
        height: 638px;
        background-color: gray;
        margin-left: -240px;
        transition-property: margin-left;
        transition-duration: 2s;
     }
     .mainmenu.active{
          margin-left: 0;
     }
     </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Правильно но не на чистом `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ на ваш вопрос.

```js
function scrolMenu() {
  var main = document.getElementById('menu');
  main.classList.toggle("menu0");
};
```

```css
#menu{
  margin-left:50px;
}
#menu.menu0{
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  </head>
  <body class="chatbg">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="mainmenu" id="menu" onclick="scrolMenu()">MARGIN MENU</div>
    <div class="chat"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Лучше не менять сам стиль с помощью `javascript`.
А дать стиль отдельному классу, и когда элемент имеет этот класс то на него подействует определенный стиль, а если нет то будет изначальный стиль.
А с помощью `javascript` просто добавить и удалить класс.
И что бы каждый раз не морочить голову `есть ли класс у элемента или нет`. (что бы понять добавить при клике или удалить) есть такой хороший метод `toggle`.

Берем элемент.(Это вы делали), потом возьмем его классы с помощью `classList`, А после этого применяем метод ՝toggle՝.
Этот метод добавляет класс если его нет, а если есть удаляет.

Answer (score 0):

сделайте чтобы по клику добавлялся/удалялся какой-нибудь класс, а дальше если есть класс `margin-left: 0px;` иначе `margin-left: -240px;` также под этот класс можно подвязать и другие изменения стилей:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <style>
      .mainmenu {
        width: 250px;
        height: 638px;
        background-color: gray;
        margin-left: -240px;
        transition-property: margin-left;
        transition-duration: 2s;
      }
      .mainmenu.show {
        margin-left: 0px;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="chatbg">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="mainmenu" id="menu" onclick="scrolMenu()"></div>
  <div class="chat"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var isClicked = false;

    function scrolMenu() {
    var main = document.getElementById('menu');
      main.classList.toggle("show");
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Прекрасный `merge` двух существующих уже ответов.))))

Comment: ответы делались одновременно, по крайней мере когда я начал писать, ещё ответов вообще не было...

Comment: И идеальное совпадение пикселей в `css` с другим ответом)))

Comment: да и с вопросом тоже... в потверждение - и там, и там не закрыта скобка в стилях....

Comment: далее эту дискуссию продолжать не стоит...